# Using Jquery Change CSS3 keyframe based on time

Tags: jquery, css, keyframe

I have been playing with CSS and Jquery to make a clock. One of the things i want to do is make the seconds rotate around the clock smoothly - to do this I am using Keyframe animation - the problem is that I need to get the current time and define what degrees the rotation starts. Right now, just using CSS I can get the rotation to start at the same spot every time, - but i need change it depending on how many seconds are in the minute.

See the example - http://codepen.io/coreykliewer/pen/GpLrPv?editors=010

```
@keyframes rot {
from {
    transform: rotate(90deg)
               translate(-25vw)
               rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: top center;
}
to {
    transform: rotate(450deg)
               translate(-25vw) 
               rotate(-450deg);
transform-origin: top center;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I just needed to append the head.

```
function timeDegree() {
  var now = new Date();
  var nowSec = now.getSeconds();
  var timeDegreeStart = 90 + (nowSec*6);
   var timeDegreeEnd = 450 + (nowSec*6);
  var str = "@keyframes rot { from { transform: rotate("+timeDegreeStart+"deg) translate(-25vw) rotate(-"+timeDegreeStart+"deg); transform-origin: top center; } to { transform: rotate("+timeDegreeEnd+"deg) translate(-25vw)  rotate(-"+timeDegreeEnd+"deg); transform-origin: top center; } }";
$('<style id="newStyle" type="text/css"></style>').text(str).appendTo('head');

    }
```